# ?android:attr/listDivider not recognised as drawable in an inset drawable

Tags: android

I have this simple resource drawable:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:drawable="?android:attr/listDivider"
       android:insetLeft="88dp"
       android:insetRight="16dp">
</inset>
```

This works alright on a Nexus 6 with 5.1, but on a Huawei U9200E with 4.0.3 I get:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #6: <inset> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

I can use  `?android:attr/listDivider` in other attributes, and I can set other drawables as the drawable for my inset drawable, but this combination doesn't work, apparently, in some devices.

Why???

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I don't know why it does not work, but I could manage to make it work programmatically. This is how:

```
    Resources r = getResources();
    TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppBaseTheme, new int[]{android.R.attr.listDivider});
    int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    Drawable divider;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        divider = getDrawable(attributeResourceId);
    } else {
        divider = r.getDrawable(attributeResourceId);
    }
    a.recycle();

    int lpx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, RIGHT_MARGIN, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    int rpx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, LEFT_MARGIN, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    InsetDrawable insetDivider = new InsetDrawable(divider, lpx, 0, rpx, 0);

    mListView.setDivider(insetDivider);
```